# Django Rest Framework requieres as not null look up field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True, default=_create_access_code, verbose_name=_("Id"))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=_("Name"))
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Description"))
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='albums', verbose_name=_("Company"))
    access_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=_create_access_code, verbose_name=_("Internal Use"))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Album")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Albums")

    def __str__(self):
        return "[{}] {} ({})".format(self.pk, self.name, self.company.id)


class Photo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Name"))
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='photos', verbose_name=_("Album"))
    photo = models.ImageField(verbose_name=_("Photo"))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Photo")
        verbose_name_plural =_("Photos")

    def __str__(self):
        return "[{}] {}".format(self.pk, self.name)
```

I am trying to make a post to the **ModelViewSet** for model `Albums`, but I get an error indicating that field `photos` is required. Even the `OPTIONS` method indicates it es required.

How can I instruct **DRF** for not considering look up fields as required? Is it some serializer setting?

Comment: What about your serializer? [anyway try this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53896050/8283848)

Answer (score 0):

You can add required=False to fields in the serializer.

```
photos = PhotoSerializer(many=True, required=False)
```

Something like this. Can you post you serializers?